# set initial sort order for digit column tablesorter jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, gridview, tablesorter

I want to sort numeric columns in my grid in descending order on first click.? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Hi Brian, I am using TableSorter plugin of jquery. I set the default settings in it. But I am unable to specify the initial sort order for each column separately. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Ven,

Use the "sortlist" option indicating you want to sort in DESCENDING order (1), rather than ASCENDING (0).

The documentation says:

"sortlist" - An array of instructions for per-column sorting and direction in the format: [[columnIndex, sortDirection], ... ] where columnIndex is a zero-based index for your columns left-to-right and sortDirection is 0 for Ascending and 1 for Descending. A valid argument that sorts ascending first by column 1 and then column 2 looks like: [[0,0],[1,0]].

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// call the tablesorter plugin
    $("table").tablesorter({
        // sort on the first column and third column, order descending (1)
        sortList: [[0,1],[2,1]]
    });
});
```

Regards Neil

Comment: Hi Neil, Thanks a lot for the quick response. I knew this. But this will sort the numeric column also during load in the descending order. I don't need this. What I need is, only the numeric column(s) in the grid should be sorted in the descending order upon first time header click, whereas other other columns, should get sorted in ascending order during first header click.

Comment: To change the initial sort order, set the `sortInitialOrder` option to either `"asc"` or `"desc"` - get more details [here](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html)